# Is there a winning strategy for this number game?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given a composite number $N_0$. Player one subtract from $N_0$ one of its prime factors and get the number $N_1$. The player two do the same with the number $N_1$ and so on. The first player to reach a prime number win.

I'm testing machine learning and would like a key solution to compare with the learned skill.

It's a perfectly defined game which is an example of a very general game on graphs that can be generalized to cover almost any game of the kind (even chess). The solution seems to be trivial (for humans), but machine learning programs can without knowing the solution search winning patterns to be compared with the correct solution.

Comment: Is $N_0$ small i.e fits in 64 bits?

Comment: @kingW3 - Yes that's enough.

Comment: Scratch 64 bits for small enough $N_0$ lets say 24 bits, you can precompute a row of numbers $T$ from $2$ to $N_0$ which indicate whether you are in a winning or losing position, from there for each $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_n^{k_n}$ where $p_i$ prime and $k_i\geq 1$, if $n$ is prime put $T[n] = \bot$since the player before you won otherwise if $T[n-p_i] =\bot$ for any $p_i$ then $T[n] =\top$ otherwise $T[n] =\bot$. Now to find factorization of $n$ use [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/)

Comment: Very interesting game (+1). I guess the structure of this game is extremely complicated since subtracting a prime will usually change the factorization completely. I do not think that this problem can be analyzed very far without just applying brute force.

Comment: @Peter - There seems to be a rather simple strategy.

Comment: What does reaching a prime number mean? Let's say we start with $4$. Then player one computes $4-2=2$. So is now player one the winner since he reached $2$ or is it player two because player one has to give the $2$ to player two?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - the first is the winner in this game, the other is a dual game.

Comment: @Lehs So you could continue the game for a bit and say the winner is the player who gets handed a $0$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - In the general case I think of a dag, a directed acyclic graph and the player that can't make a move lose. Both cases in your comment are possible games.

Comment: @Lehs Well, 0 has infinitely many prime divisors. So there is always a possible next move. The only two numbers for which there is no move are $-1$ and $1$ but if you start at another number you can never get to them!

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain - So the rule is  that you must be able to go to a positive number.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain The rules as stated rule out the possibility to reach $1$ , $0$ or a negative number. It has a reason why Lehs designed it this way to ensure that the game always ends in a finite amount of time, and there must be a winner.

Comment: @Peter Technically speaking Lehs did not require the composite number $N_0$ to be positive ;-)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain If the possibility of negative numbers is not explicitely stated, almost everyone would assume that with "composite" and "prime" numbers positive integers greater than $1$ are meant.

Comment: Do you realize, @Jyrki, that your edit failed to improve the post, and yet you edited, thus sending the post to the reopen queue?  You're smart, so I assume you knowingly did an edit knowingly not improving the post you want reopened?

Comment: @Lehs, you might enjoy taking a look at my game "Factor Subtractor" -- see https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g10gift/games/Cipra_Barry-Factor_Subtractor.pdf for a description.

Comment: @BarryCipra - Similar but better. In general it's about directed graphs. Chess become a very big directed graph with two different colors for the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=\{n\in Z_{>2}|\;\; 2|n \wedge \exists p\in\mathbb P_{>2}: p|n \}\cup\{4\}$. Say it's your turn on the position $n\in W$. If you select a move $n-p$ where $p>2$ then the opponent is on an odd number $n-p\notin W$ and must select to subtract an odd prime $q$, where $p|(n-p)$ and $q|(n-p-q)$. But $(n-p-q)\in W$ since it's even with a prime factor $>2$.

By induction you may stay in a path in $W$ and as your number get smaller you will get a position $2r$ where $r\in\mathbb P_{>2}$ and win with the move $2r-r$, if and only if the opponent's odd number doesn't reach a prime befor you do. But the number $n-p-q$ is a prime only if  $n-p-q=q$ (since $q|(n-p-q)$), that is if $n-p=2q$ which is impossible since $n-p$ is odd.

---

There is no winning strategy on an odd number. From an odd number one have to go an even number that's not a power of two. The other player then have a position in $W$ which is possible to keep while subtracting an odd prime from the even number, giving the opponent a position at an other odd non prime number.

```
Example for start 15 and 20
Losing position: 
15,10,5
   12,9,6,3
Winning position:
20,15 se above.
```

Comment: Please clarify this strategy in an example. What is the criterion for a winning position in plain text ?

Comment: @Peter - I choosed low numbers to avoid many alternatives.

Comment: Why does "$15$" appear in the list of losing positions as well as in the list of winning positions ? This cannot be the case !

Comment: @Peter - 15 is a losing position but 20 is winning position. When the game start at 20 the opponent get the position 15 by 20-5.

Comment: You completely classified the numbers which are bad for the player to move ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130332/discussion-between-peter-and-lehs).

Comment: Why is $10$ a losing position? From $10$ you can go to $8$, forcing the other player to leave $6$, when you can move to $3$ and win. Undoubtedly I misunderstood either the rules or what you are saying, but don't know exactly what?

Comment: Why does one edit a post, not improving it, @JyrkiLahtonen, to send it to the reopen queue?  Clearly you intended to do so in hopes of having the question reopened, after having voted to undelete it.  There is a dedicated thread in meta for above board efforts to reopen a question.

Comment: @amWhy I was the last to vote to undelete. I would have preferred the OP to add the information I did as well as the information I requested in my edit (and the comment above). I could not invite them to do so without first voting to undelete. I knew that this action would get a mixed response, and I feel a bit bad about it. If the OP cannot add anything, and the question will get redeleted, then I will go through with [the procedure](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402/11619).

Comment: @Jyrki Thanks for the explanation.  I very much understand now.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - All even composite numbers are winning positions to the player making next move. The game have a trivial solution but works for testing learning strategies. The learned solution can then be compared with the trivial solution.

Comment: @Lehs Then I don't understand the rules. From 8 the only legal move is to 6, which is a winning position for the other player. So 8 is a losing position, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Right, I forgot to exclude powers of 2.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out that the game is not as difficult as I initially thought. I don't know if you familiar with Sprague-Grundy numbers associated to positions of games like this? Anyway, It turns out that the SG value of $n$ is $0$ if, $n$ is either odd or a power of two. The value is $2$, if $n$ is divisible by four, but not a power of two, and the value is $1$ for all the other even numbers. Basically meaning that you never need to look ahead any further than two moves. Too bad. May be having more allowed moves would make for a more exciting game, but I don't have any suggestions in mind.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I only just now saw your last comment, after having posted a comment below the OP. You might find something to like in "Factor Subtractor" as well. The link, again, is https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g10gift/games/Cipra_Barry-Factor_Subtractor.pdf

Comment: Thanks @BarryCipra! Needless to I downloaded your manuscript. Giving a player a degree of control of the moves of the next player like that seems to fit the bill. If I find the time I may try and Sprague-Grundy that, undoubtedly simply to reproduce that list to the extent my limited programming skille allow :-)